# How to send an S3 Notification Event to a SNS Topic in Cloudformation in YAML?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I am trying to build a Cloudformation script in YAML. The objective is when a file is created in the S3 bucket (S3BucketTest) it will send a notification to an SNS Topic (SNSTest) that will later send a message to an SQS Queue (not built yet). The thing I need help with is, in the TopicConfiguration section, how do you pull the ARN of the topic for the S3 Notification Event? I want it to be dynamic and not hard coded. I've tried Fn::GetAtt, but that didn't work either. Any thoughts?

Note: Don't mind formatting and global naming issues. I changed the names to make it simpler and formatting got messed up when pasting. Thank you.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: CloudFormation template for s3 bucket
Resources:
 S3BucketTest
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: S3BucketTest
      AccessControl: Private
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
      LoggingConfiguration:
        DestinationBucketName: log-test
        LogFilePrefix: testing-logs
      NotificationConfiguration:
       TopicConfigurations:
           - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
             **Topic: !Ref: SNSTest**
S3BucketLogs:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Description: Creating Amazon S3 bucket from CloudFormation
    Properties:
      BucketName: log-test
      AccessControl: Private
      AccessControl: LogDeliveryWrite
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
   DivDevSNS:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
        DisplayName: SNSTest
        TopicName: SNSTest
```

Comment: You can address code formatting by surrounding it in `\`\`\`triple backquotes\`\`\`` or by indenting with four spaces.

Comment: Siehe https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-rollback-email/.